# How to get updated width of content after a css change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify the css class of my body element.

Before modifying the class, I check the scroll width of my content:

```
$(window.document.body).prop('scrollWidth');  // 800px
```

Now I modify the css class and check the scroll width again:

```
$(window.document.body).prop('class', someCssClassName);
$(window.document.body).prop('scrollWidth');  // still reports 800px
```

I know the scroll width should not be 800px after this particular change. I start a timer and keep printing the scroll width, and after a few ms I see it change to 600px.

So it seems like I can't immediately get the updated content width (or I'm misinterpreting what's going on).

Is there a way to get notified when the re-flow is complete, so that I might get the updated width?

I don't want to set a timer and keep checking, if possible.

I'm trying this in an android WebView.. browser.. . So I'm not sure if this behavior will be the same if I try in a desktop browser.

Thank you

Comment: Could you create a demo?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? Your code is equivalent to `document.body.scrollWidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question: accessing the `scrollWidth` property automatically flushes any style change (forces a reflow) and then returns the computed value. This happens synchronously, hence you don't need to "wait" for the reflow to complete -- the JS will simply freeze while the reflow happens and then return the correct `scrollWidth` value.

You are actually facing a very specific Blink/WebKit bug in their `scrollWidth` implementation regarding the `body` element.

---

I've simplified your code a bit by removing some unnecessary jQuery abstraction ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uKH6/3/)):

```
document.body.className = 'w600px';
console.log(
    document.body.scrollWidth, // Firefox: 600, Chrome: viewport width
    $(document.body).width()   // 600 in both browsers
);
```

```
.w600px {
    width: 600px;
}
```

---

From the [CSSOM `element.scrollWidth` spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollwidth):

> 3. If the element is the HTML `body` element, the Document is in quirks mode and the element has no associated scrolling box, return max(viewport scrolling area width, viewport width).

It seems like Chrome is not checking whether the document is in Quirks mode and returning the viewport (scrolling) width independent of the document mode.

You should open a [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) in these cases.

---

#### Workarounds

It really depends on your use case. `$(document.body).width()` is usually fine, unless the content overflows the `body` element's width.

Alternatively, wrap all the page's contents inside of a `div` and use it to apply the class and to retrieve the `scrollWidth` from.

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer - I thought I was going crazy. Yes unfortunately I'm in scenario #2, where my content overflows the body element's width. I'll try the second approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 function getprop( el, prop ) {
      var props = window.getComputedStyle (
      $(el).get(0)).getPropertyValue(prop);
      return String(props);
    };
console.log(getprop("body", "width"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6uKH6/5/